# How to i get class instance from interface in JUnit test case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

In my Junit test case , i am trying to get instance of class from Factory but its always return null, APersistenceDAO and BPersistenceDAO classes implements TestDao

```
@Component
public class TestDAOFactory {
 public TestDao(String type) {
     TestDaodao= null;
     System.out.println("dao type "+type);
     switch(type) {
    
     case "A":
         dao = new APersistenceDAO();
         break;
     case "B":
         dao= new BPersistenceDAO();
         break;
     
     }
    
    return dao;
     
 }
```

This is my junit test code to get Dao reference

```
 @MockBean
  private TestDAOFactory daoFactory;
@Test
  void populateCacheFromPersistence() {
      
      TestDao dao = daoFactory.getDao("A");//always getting null
}
```

Can you please kindly check what i am missing here?

i have added configuration as well

```
  @Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public TestDAOFactory daoFactory() {
            return Mockito.mock(Test.class);
        }
}
```

and from main test class , i have tried to get instance  using

```
@Autowired
  private TestDAOFactory daoFactory;
```

Comment: It seems like you are trying to mock your object, but you forget the actual mocking part

Comment: When i Mock TestDao , i am getting difference issue something like TestDao has ATestDao and BTestDao

Comment: @Stultuske please let me know what i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

You are using a mock on the class you are testing. It will return null if you do not configure it otherwise. You need to actually instantiate the class.

```
// @MockBean <-- Remove this
private TestDAOFactory daoFactory = new TestDAOFactory(); // Or add it in a setup method
@Test
void populateCacheFromPersistence() { 
  TestDao dao = daoFactory.getDao("A");//always getting null
}
```

Comment: thanks , How to configure with Mock?

Comment: Either you want to test the class or you want to mock it but you can't do both... A mock would look something like `when(daoFactory .getDao(anyString()).thenReturn(new APersistenceDAO());` but that defies the purpose of the test

Comment: i have tried this way aswell but still not working , i have a class which implements  ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> here also referring to daoFactory there its failing , do i need to setup this even before tests start? if yes how to do that

Answer (score 0):

i can able to fix it by adding @Profile("test") in configuration class

```
@Profile("test") 
  @Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public TestDAOFactory daoFactory() {
            return Mockito.mock(Test.class);
        }
}
```